# Drawbacks of opening many FileOutputStream

Tags: java

What are the drawbacks of opening many FileOutputStream at any point of time? My aim is to write a big chunk of data, break them and write them into separate files.

Comment: You could run out of system file handles.  There might also be an increased overhead due to the multiple disk writing.  Assuming you're doing this through the use of multiple threads, that could also be a drain on system resources...

Comment: And what does "many" mean anyway? Eight isn't "many".

Comment: As per the design, data is divided into fixed number of rows and hence the number of files are not known

Comment: For loop? Write one file at a time.